# Mixing monospace and normal text doesn't look nice

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown-rendering, formatting

Sometimes I want to pluralize a Python class name, but the plural "s" should not be monospace, since it's not code. For example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12737874):

[image: Screenshot of answer with the text "For more about Sessions"]

The letters should line up.

Comment: _"The letters should line up."_ How would you suggest it does?

Comment: Looks nice to me

Comment: So...this is actually a more valid point than it might initially seem.  The `font-size` of inline code blocks is `13px`, while post body text is `15px`.  Adjusting the former to `15px` [does make it line up a bit better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XF7a.png).

Comment: But it still looks ugly to mix them, @RyanM.

Comment: I have never claimed to be a designer.  I'm just pointing out the problem :-)

Comment: The solution to this problem does not require a designer, @RyanM. It needs [a doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdDt2.jpg).

Comment: @CodyGray you sound [like Steve Jobs](https://www.macrumors.com/2010/06/24/steve-jobs-describes-iphone-4-signal-strength-a-non-issue/). I talk like this, so I should be able to write like this.

Comment: You talk with inline code formatting? Do you, like, switch to a monotone when reading text formatted in a monospace typeface? I guess that's kind of cool. Probably also annoying. What a coincidence. :-)

Comment: you know exactly what I mean. I mean when I talk I pluralize nouns that are code. When I write nouns that are code, I write them in monospace, but putting the plural in the monospace would be wrong because the "s" is not code.

Comment: I did not know what you meant. Yes, of course, you grammatically inflect identifiers that happen to be used in code. So do I. But that brings us back to the point: when you read code aloud, you do not demarcate it in any special way. You assume that your listeners can figure out from context that "Session" is a class name. So, why would it be different when you write/type it? If you don't need some kind of special code formatting when you speak, why do you need it when you format text in an answer? It should be clear from context, without the need for an eyesore.

Comment: @CodyGray why do we ever monospace code? Whatever your answer is why I want to do it in line. The "eyesore" is the fault of the design, not my fault for mixing fonts. It's possible to make mixed monospace and regular fonts look nice, I will find you an example.

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy "*why do we ever monospace code? Whatever your answer is why I want to do it in line*" but that's not really correct. *Grammatically*. If you want to talk about "sessions", then that's not the concept is not code. It seems you're linking to documentation about some thing called `Session` (I hope it's some sort of class) in which case you don't talk about *multiple* of them. The correct wording would be "To learn more about `Session` : <link to documentation on `Session`>. If you want to talk about multiples of `Session`, then it's probably "`Session` objects"

Comment: @VLAZ what if I want to say "you're going to get a bunch of [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError)s"? I know I can rephrase anything to add a space after the code, but I want to phrase things the way I phrase them.

Comment: "This will raise a `RuntimeError` multiple times" or "You will get multiple instances of `RuntimeError` with this code" Sure, you can also pluralise it but it's a bit awkward to work into written text anyway. It's not hard to reword slightly. Written text does not need to conform 1:1 with spoken word rules. Sometimes we avoid some spoken and/or informal rules. Similar to how for a Q&A on the site we should avoid writing things like "this code slaps" or "for loops are strong in this meta".

Comment: BTW you can also just say "you're going to get a bunch of runtime errors" - the term "runtime error" is already a thing already. You don't really need to use the class name. Assuming it's clear that it's going to be a `RuntimeError`  *or* that the actual exception class doesn't matter since you're just referring to errors that all happen at runtime.

Comment: A workaround is to use italics instead (HTML `em` is required as Markdown requires a space to either side of the asteriskes)

Comment: I sometimes remember how someone told me half a year ago to change the way I talk to avoid a font formatting issue and it still makes me laugh.

Answer (score 5):

So the cause of this is that ...well, they are misaligned.  By 2 pixels:

[image: line showing that the body text is 2px taller than the code block]

The fact that it's 2 pixels is unsurprising, given that the `font-size` of inline code blocks is `13px`, while post body text is `15px`.

Adjusting the `font-size` of code to `15px` does in fact make it line up better:

[image: more lined-up text]

Comment: That gap in the word cannot be unseen though. This reminds me of that old saying we're not allowed to use anymore. Polishing a t... eapot.

Comment: Yeah, it could probably use some other adjustments...but it looks *less* bad, at least.

Comment: But then code blocks just get too large and bold due to the different font, so this isn't really a solution.

Comment: I'd personally lean toward applying this to _just_ inline code blocks, and leaving non-inline code blocks with the current, smaller font size.

Comment: Text is typically aligned on the baseline. So if the bottom of the ses in `Session` don't line up with the bottom of the terminal s, then there's something wrong. Obviously, it's trivial to simply reword the sentence to avoid the problem altogether: "Read more about [the `Session` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects)" ;-)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ugh. Code markup inside a link. You do your chosen screen name justice.